# Error using zeros Out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

When I try running

```
Adj = zeros(x*y);
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Error using zeros
>
> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

where `x*y=37901`. The occupancy of my PC storage is

[image]

I know the C drive doesn't have much space but 34.2 GB should be more than enough for creating a `37901*37901` matrix.

When I run the `memory` command this is what I got:

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:        4825 MB (5.059e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:        4825 MB (5.059e+09 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:       12369 MB (1.297e+10 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):       12218 MB (1.281e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

How can I solve this issue? (I am using MATLAB 2017b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, coding side, variables are normally stored into memory (your computer `RAM`) rather than into hard disk space. That's what your error complains about... you don't have enough memory to store the variable you want to allocate.

The default numerical variable used by Matlab is `double`, which is used to represent double precision floating-point values and takes up `8` bytes of memory. Hence, you are trying to allocate:

```
37901 * 37901 * 8  = 11491886408 bytes
                  ~= 10.7 gigabytes
```

When you only have something like `11.9` gigabytes of available memory and Matlab is telling you that you can't allocate an array greater than `4.7` gigabytes. As a workaround, I suggest you to take a look at [Tall Arrays](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html), which are a Matlab feature tailored around handling very big data flows:

> Tall arrays are used to work with out-of-memory data that is backed by
>   a datastore. Datastores enable you to work with large data sets in
>   small chunks that individually fit in memory, instead of loading the
>   entire data set into memory at once. Tall arrays extend this
>   capability to enable you to work with out-of-memory data using common
>   functions.
>
> **What is a Tall Array?**
>
> Since the data is not loaded into memory all at once, tall arrays can be arbitrarily large in the first dimension
>   (that is, they can have any number of rows). Instead of writing
>   special code that takes into account the huge size of the data, such
>   as with techniques like MapReduce, tall arrays let you work with large
>   data sets in an intuitive manner that is similar to the way you would
>   work with in-memory MATLAB® arrays. Many core operators and functions
>   work the same with tall arrays as they do with in-memory arrays.
>   MATLAB works with small chunks of the data at a time, handling all of
>   the data chunking and processing in the background, so that common
>   expressions, such as A+B, work with big data sets.
>
> **Benefits of Tall Arrays**
>
> Unlike in-memory arrays, tall arrays typically remain unevaluated until you request that the calculations
>   be performed using the gather function. This deferred evaluation
>   allows you to work quickly with large data sets. When you eventually
>   request output using gather, MATLAB combines the queued calculations
>   where possible and takes the minimum number of passes through the
>   data. The number of passes through the data greatly affects execution
>   time, so it is recommended that you request output only when
>   necessary.